# C#/.Net Error: MySql.Data Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, mysql

I get this exception on my Windows 7 64bit in application running in VS 2008 express. I am using Connector/Net 6.2.2.0:

```
Message:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source:
MySql.Data in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int32& insertedId)

Stack trace:
in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int32& insertedId)
in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId)
in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Close()
in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Close()
in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
in System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize()

No inner exception.
```

This exception is unhalted and the debugger dont point on any code line. It just say "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. MySql.Data"

This error is really hard to repeat. On my Windows XP 32bit is all ok. Could it be error in 64bit Windows 7?

Thank you very much for your answers.
Regards,
simon

Comment: run pieces of code to spot the line that is causing the error... the most probable problem is that you left something unasigned...

Comment: there is problem how to find concrete pieces of code. I am not able to find int becose error is raised from Mysql.Data dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Connector/Net 6.2.2. is not meant for 64 bit platform. ODBC connector available for 64 bit.

Comment: Thank you, thats my opinion too. But I need to be sure before changing the connector.